# Old black and white movie where there was a giant clock on an alien planet that regulated universal time

Tags: story-identification

I saw an old black and white space movie in 1968, where at the end the spacemen had to travel to an alien planet and re-start a giant clock which controlled universal time.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure that's enough to go off, can you please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that you saw *The Wizard of Mars* (1965).  It was in color, but you might have seen it on a black and white TV.  In the remote future year 1974, a spaceship crashes on Mars and the crew find a Martian city frozen in time and are given the task of restarting a clock to unfreeze the city.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059920/[1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059920/)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Mars[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Mars)

https://www.google.com/search?q=the+wizard+of+mars+(1965)&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjborWt6P3ZAhWluVkKHeoeAV8Q_AUIDCgD&biw=1920&bih=949[3](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20wizard%20of%20mars%20(1965)&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjborWt6P3ZAhWluVkKHeoeAV8Q_AUIDCgD&biw=1920&bih=949)

Comment: YESS! THIS WAS IT! I've been searching for this for YEARS! I did watch  it on a B&W tv when I was 8 and my recollection of the details had changed over the years. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome.  I couldn't begin to count all the movies and TV shows I assumed were in black and white because I first saw them on black and white TVs, only to later learn that they were in color.